# Haskell data variable

Tags: list, variables, haskell, tree

I have this simple list structure where every leaf holds two values (a and b) and every node holds one value (a)

```
data List a b = Leaf (a, b) | Node (a, (List a b)) deriving Show
```

And I have this function just returning the value of a node or the first value of a leaf

```
func (Leaf (a, b)) = a
func (Node (a, c)) = a
```

Is there a way avoid one of these pattern matches? In fact I'm working on a ternary-tree and functions which have more than one argument, so I have a lot of pattern matches which are all doing the same thing.

I thought about something like this

```
func (var (a, b)) = a
```

where var can be a leaf or a node, but this does not work.

Comment: `(a, b)` can be thought of as one value, actually. And the answer is, I think, *no*, or at least *no, unless* you're fine with using SYB.

Comment: As a side issue, you have more syntax than you need. you could do the equivalent structure `List a b = Leaf a b | Node a (List a b)` and then define the two patterns as `top (Leaf a _) = a` and `top (Node a _) = a`.

Comment: The word 'Variable' is a curse word in Haskell-Land. The word is _datatype_, not 'datavariable'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're comfortable with it, you can refactor your type as:

```
data List a b = L (a, Either b (List a b)) deriving Show
```

Then,

```
func :: List a b -> a
func (L (a,_)) = a
```

Previous values like

```
Leaf (a, b)
Node (a, list)
```

are now written as

```
L (a, Left b)
L (a, Right list)
```

Depending on your code, this might be more convenient to use.

However, keep in mind that if you need to access the second component of the pair, you need to pattern match anyway. It is likely that your current datatype is more convenient, overall, than this alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it by adding a help function returning the first value

```
gf (Leaf (a, b)) = a
gf (Node (a, b)) = a
```

So I can always use this function

```
func x = gf x
```

There are still two pattern matches but in case of more complex functions expecting more than one argument it is useful to avoid a lot of pattern matches

i.e

```
addValues (Leaf (a, b)) (Leaf (c, d)) (Leaf (e, f)) = a + c + e 
addValues (Leaf (a, b)) (Leaf (c, d)) (Node (e, f)) = a + c + e 
addValues (Leaf (a, b)) (Node (c, d)) (Leaf (e, f)) = a + c + e 
addValues (Leaf (a, b)) (Node (c, d)) (Node (e, f)) = a + c + e 
addValues (Node (a, b)) (Leaf (c, d)) (Leaf (e, f)) = a + c + e 
addValues (Node (a, b)) (Leaf (c, d)) (Node (e, f)) = a + c + e 
addValues (Node (a, b)) (Node (c, d)) (Leaf (e, f)) = a + c + e 
addValues (Node (a, b)) (Node (c, d)) (Node (e, f)) = a + c + e
```

can now be written as

```
addValues (a, b, c) = (gf a) + (gf b) + (gf c)
```